# Azure. Growing Number of Free Trials Subscriptions in Company's Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager

Last time I checked, a month ago there were 3 "Free Trial" Subscriptions in company's Azure AD. I was only able to see them once I elevated myself from Global Administrator to User Access Administrator. Now there are 6 "Free Trial" Subscriptions, 3 more than before.

- How were these Subscriptions created? Did somebody sign up for Free Trial using company's mail, so that Free Trial got added into company's Azure AD?
- How can I find out who created the subscriptions?
- None of the subscriptions have Role assignments in Access control
  (IAM), yet all of them have Classic administrators. Is this normal?
- Should we be concerned about this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - How were these Subscriptions created? Did somebody sign up for Free    Trial using company's mail, so that Free Trial got added into company's Azure AD?

If you use  the work account(company email)to register Azure free subscription, it will be automatically associated with the tenant which contains the account

> - How can I find out who created the subscriptions?

As far as I know, regarding the Azure free subscriptions, the account that is used to create subscriptions is automatically set as both the Account Administrator and Service Administrator. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/rbac-and-directory-admin-roles#classic-subscription-administrator-roles)

> - None of the subscriptions have Role assignments in Access control    (IAM), yet all of them have Classic administrators. Is this normal? Should we be concerned about this situation?

We can use Classic subscription administrators to manage who can access Azure subscription and resources. The classic subscription administrator role is relatively simple.  We can't control permissions precisely. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/rbac-and-directory-admin-roles).

Comment: Thank you very much for these answers. How can we forbid this? We don't want users to be able to create Free Trial subscriptions in our Azure AD.

Comment: @WinBoss if you use the work account to register the Azure free subscription, it is inevitable.

Comment: Surely there must be a setting that will disallow that?

Comment: @WinBoss As far as I know, we have no way to disallow that.